# How do I remove Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows

I used Ubuntu to download Windows 10 and put in my usb. And when I try to install Windows it says that I need drivers to put it in and it doesn't detect any.

Comment: How is this related to removing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to install Windows onto a drive which currently contains Ubuntu, and you wish to do so in a manner which is not a dual boot, or any type of arrangement involving Ubuntu.  If that is the case, you aren't going to find a lot of people on this site who will go out of their way to help you, but I will see what I can offer.

In keeping with the spirit of this site, which is to educate and assist, I will only say that what you wish to do, first requires that you erase the hard drive entirely, and that you then seek help ELSEWHERE for how to install Windows onto that hard drive from scratch.

My advice is to begin by booting to whatever Live-Boot CD or USB stick which you initially used to install Ubuntu onto your hard drive, and then open the disk utility to erase your hard drive.  It is really easy to figure out how to do that.  I could get a lot more detailed, but as you have not revealed which version of Ubuntu you have installed, it would be difficult to ensure that the precise instructions I gave you would be entirely accurate.